# Logback FileAppender - logfile is empty?

Tags: logging, logback

In a project I have the following on the classpath:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/logback-classic.jar,
 lib/logback-core.jar,
 lib/slf4j-api.jar
```

and the following in the build.properties:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               lib/logback-classic.jar,\
               lib/logback-core.jar,\
               lib/slf4j-api.jar,\
               logback.xml
```

In the root I also have a logback.xml file containing:

```
<!--   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> -->
<!--     <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout"> -->
<!--       <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n -->
<!--       </Pattern> -->
<!--     </layout> -->
<!--   </appender> -->
  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <File>logs\\logfile.log</File>
    <Append>true</Append>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
      <Pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
      </Pattern>
    </layout>
  </appender>
</configuration>
```

In a class that gets executed at startup I have:

```
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class.getName());
  public Object start(IApplicationContext context) {
    logger.debug("debug string");
    logger.warn("warn string");
    logger.error("error string");
```

When I build and run my application a file logs\logfile.log is created in the root of my application but its empty. If I use the ConsoleAppender and enable the console it works fine.

Why does logback not write to the logfile when using the FileAppender?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried with adding file appender-ref to root in logback.xml as shown below:

```
<root level="debug">
   <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
   <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

Comment: Superb answer Thanks Girish!