# Logback empty log file is getting created

Tags: logback

In my application is using `RolingFileAppender` with size based triggering policy main classes initializes log file using logback configuration file. When main class is invoked using a shell script, I see log messages are correctly going to log file that conf define but in addition it also created empty logfile with scriptname
say ABC.sh calls MainClass which is supposed to write to logback123.log now all messages are going to  logback123.log fine but there is extra empty ABC.log file is getting created.
Any thoughts on this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILEOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/opt/agents/upgradeSC91Temp/mbs/logs/watchdog.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
         <fileNamePattern>/opt/agents/upgradeSC91Temp/mbs/logs/watchdog_%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex> <maxIndex>10</maxIndex> </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="com.aptare.dc.util.LogbackSizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize> </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder> <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %C{0}.%-5M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS} %-5p %C{0}.%-5M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.aptare.dc.util.LogWriterInitializer">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
       </logger>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Share the logback.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Diogo for looking into it, I added logback.xml but after editing question and posting it , it does not look complete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logback FileAppender - logfile is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479606/logback-fileappender-logfile-is-empty)